# AWS Instance Ubuntu 20.04 - Backup and restore

Tags: apache2, backup, aws

**TL;DR:**

I have a AWS Lightsail Instance and need to restore it on another AWS account, which AWS does not support. How do I fully backup my current instance, and then restore it on another instance?

**Details:**

My AWS Lightsail instance needs to be moved to another AWS account, and there is no easy way from AWS to backup my instance and transfer that backup to another account and restore from there. There is an option to do this via EC2, but not quite what I am looking for.

I am looking for a simple way to back-up my LAMP setup including the /var/www/html/ folder, Apache2 config, etc. into a file, download it to my local computer, and then upload to the new instance and somehow extract it there. How do I best approach this?

I am working off a AWS Lightsail Instance running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a standard LAMP setup including PHP 7.3, Apache2 and Mysql 8.0. Thanks a lot.